# Unrecognized selector sent to instance UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

i have looked up the same questions, but the answers given don't seem to fix my problem.

I'm creating an app where you can add and remove your school marks. In my view controller i have created a `UITableView`. Within there there's a custom `UITableViewCell`, called `TableViewCell`. To delete a cell i need to get it's row. I try that by using the following code in the `TableViewCell` class:

```
- (IBAction)DeleteMark:(id)sender {

   UITableView *superTableView = [self superview];
   NSIndexPath *path = [superTableView indexPathForCell:self];
   NSInteger *index = [path row];
   NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", index]);
}
```

When i run the code it shows the following error:

```
-[UITableViewWrapperView indexPathForCell:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa825a00
```

As i said before i tried the solutions given on the forums, but none of them worked.

**EDIT**

Here's my code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

   TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


   float weight = [[_editableClass.markWeights objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]floatValue];
   float mark = [[_editableClass.classMarks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]floatValue];

   cell.MarkTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", mark];
   cell.MarkWeight.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", weight];
   [cell.DeleteButton setTag:indexPath.row];
   return cell;
}
```

Comment: When/Where did you call DeleteMark method?

Comment: self in this case means the current UITableViewCell

Comment: @Viraj Padsala  I call the DeleteMark method whenever a 'delete' button is pressed within the TableViewCell

Comment: then set tag of that button as indexpath.row and at time of deleting delete row of that tag.i'm posing answer

Comment: What is `UITableViewWrapperView`?  From the error, it looks like this is not the actual `UITableView`, but perhaps a subclass of the cell's `contentView`.  Using `[self superView]` is fragile because it makes an assumption that the `UITableView` is always the direct superview, which is actually not guaranteed to be the case.

Comment: @Bek I also don't know what 'UITableViewWrapperView' means. So what you're saying is that i should use `[[self superView]superView];`?

Comment: You can definitely try that.  Put a breakpoint in that method so you can inspect what you get back as `superTableView` to see if that's right.  Apple periodically changes the contentView layout for `UITableViewCell`, so I've been burned in at least 2 iOS upgrades by assuming how many superviews up the table is.  <-- This is more a side note to you for later...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do something like what you are after you could try to set up a delegate to pass back the cell object so you can find the index from the tableView. I have tried to make an example below. For tidiness I have omitted import statements.

ViewController header file

```
@interface subClassViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate,TableViewCellDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end
```

ViewController implementation file

```
@implementation subClassViewController

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //setup cell...

    cell.delegate = self;
    return cell;
}

- (void)deletePressedOnCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
{
    NSInteger index = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell].row;

    // do something with index
}

@end
```

TableViewCell header file

```
@protocol TableViewCellDelegate

- (void)deletePressedOnCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell;

@end

@interface TableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<TableViewCellDelegate>delegate;

@end
```

TableViewCell implementation file

```
@implementation TableViewCell

- (IBAction)DeleteMark:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate deletePressedOnCell:self];
}

@end
```

Comment: Also here : `-[EditMarksViewController DeleteMark:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a754a60`

Comment: i managed to fix that bug. But now when i press the top button it says `(null)` and the other buttons give the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

Comment: Are you still calling    cell.MarkTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", mark];
   cell.MarkWeight.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", weight];
   [cell.DeleteButton setTag:indexPath.row]; in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: I just tested this and it works. If you are getting bad access, make sure that all of the outlets and actions are connected correctly and then replace your data with a simple array to test things more easily. I meant this to be a help on the protocol and delegate example. You will have to make changes to both some of the code and your storyboard if you want this exact example to work for you

Comment: I tweaked the code, and it's working now! Thanks a lot man. I'm really learning objective c. And the delegate part is really hard for me to understand. I think i get it now!

Answer (score 0):

In your UITableview Delegate method cellForRowAtIndexPath set tag of your button:-

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 .....
 cell.yourdeletebutton.tag=indexPath.row;
}
```

Now in your delete method it looks like:-

```
- (IBAction)DeleteMark:(id)sender {

    UIButton *tappedButton = (UIButton*)sender;
    DeleteIndex=tappedButton.tag;
    NSLog(@"delete row at indexpath :%@", DeleteIndex]);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. When i press the delete button from the top cell it says "null". And when i press the second button it gives me an EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: add this method in cellforrowatindexpath [cell.yourdeletebutton addTarget:self action:@selector(DeleteMark:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Answer (score 0):

You can use by `[sender tag]`,

```
[cell.btnDelete setTag:indexPath.row];
[cell.btnDelete addTarget:self action:@selector(DeleteMark:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Method,

```
- (IBAction) DeleteMark:(id)sender {

   NSInteger *index = [sender tag];
   NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", index]);

   // Your Code...

   //For Eg.
   Object *obj = [YOUR_ARRAY objectAtIndex:[sender tag]];
   // You'll get object of particular index.

   // Your Code...
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: On the first delete button the log says "null", and the second button gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS... weird...

Comment: @Teddynieuws Please add '[cell.DeleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(YOUR METHOD:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];' line

Comment: @Teddynieuws In your code, there is no line for Add Target. It'll create issue if you have bind with cell IBOutlet. Because Cells are generated at runtime. So please add target by coding as I suggested.

Comment: Yeah i forgot that part. Still getting an error... `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[EditMarksViewController DeleteMark:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7966da20'`

Comment: @Teddynieuws Have you replace my method & code with yours ??

Comment: As well as, check this line :: [cell.btnDelete addTarget:self action:@selector(DeleteMark:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]

Comment: This error mainly indicates, it's not finding particular method inside class. So please check for "DeleteMark:"... not "DeleteMark::"

Comment: I needed to change the target to `cell` to let it at least print something. I now have this `[cell.DeleteButton addTarget:cell action:@selector(DeleteMark:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];` It's still printing out `(null)`

Comment: Using `self` as target gives the unrecognized selector error

Comment: Add Target 'self' not cell. where DeleteMark method located ?

Comment: the DeleteMark method is located inside the cell class

Comment: Put it inside 'EditMarksViewController' class and check for proper index & object.

Comment: It again prints `(null)` for the first delete button and `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on the second button

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't rely on `[[[[sender superview] superview] superview] superview]`, what if Apple decide to make some changes and add/remove another layer of subview.
The idea with tags is not ideal neither.

I would recommended you to use delegate pattern or blocks.
Please have a look how closures works. Note that it's written in swift but it could be easily translated to Objective-C.

In your `TableViewCell` add handler property:

```
var buttonPressHandler: (() -> ())?
```

Add IBAction which must be connected to button touch event (you could do it in storyboard):

```
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        // Call handler when button is pressed
        buttonPressHandler?()
    }
```

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you only needs to set up the handler:

```
    cell.buttonPressHandler = {
        print("Button pressed: \(indexPath.row)")
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Get the index path of the row using following code

```
- (void)tapped:(UIButton *) sender {

   UITableViewCell * tCell;
   NSComparisonResult order = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion compare: @"7.2" options: NSNumericSearch];
   if (order == NSOrderedDescending) {
      tCell = (BusinessFavoriteCell *)[[[[sender superview] superview] superview] superview];
   } else {
      tCell = (BusinessFavoriteCell *)[[[sender superview] superview] superview];
   }
   NSIndexPath * iPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:tCell];
}
```

Here, `tCell` is the `UITableViewCell` which is loaded in `cellForRowIndexpath` method.

Comment: Looks like 'self.tableView' is not found on the object type `TableViewCell`

Comment: self.tableview is nothing but a your tableview. In your question you have added a tableview in your controller's view in storyboard. Lets have a IBOutlet reference of that tableview and use that IBOutlet object reference in place of self.tableview.